How to solve the problem that the Cancel Request function of SC is invalid？
I found that on the Returns details page of the SC website, after clicking Cancel Request, the message promptsGood! Your request was successfully cancelled., but the actual RMA status has not changed.

Why is this?

Is it because CANCEL URL ROOT is incorrect? How should CANCEL URL ROOT be set specifically?
